# Running Python toolbox tool both standalone from other tools within same Python toolbox?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox

I have created a Python toolbox for work that has two tools inside.  These tools use the toolbox template and so have a **init**, getParameterInfo, etc.

I want to be able to run one tool both standalone and call it inside other tools within that toolbox.  I can't seem to get the parameters correct though.

```
class foo(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages)
        print parameter[0]
        return

class bar(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages)
        foo("hello, world)
        return
```

I have tried adding a parameter to the **init**(self, parameter) or the foo class but I can't get it to work.

I am new to Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) and ArcGIS in general.

Comment: You have mentioned ArcPy and ArcGIS but your code seems to be pure Python. Can you edit your question to make clear whether you are trying to write a Python toolbox or Python script tools in a standard toolbox, please?

Comment: I corrected the question.  Hopefully its more clear.  Though it is mostly a python question, I can't figure out how to make the class take both parameters given from a UI and passed programmatically when used in a different script.  Thanks!

Comment: This link is for Python script tools in standard toolboxes and does not mention Python toolboxes but it may give you some ideas: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/04/pythontemplate/ I do not know if what you are trying to do is possible.

Comment: I have a feeling what you're trying to do won't work, but can't confirm right now. One way that should work was if you import the tool into itself using arcpy.ImportToolbox() with a path to the PYT itself, then call arcpy.foo()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest option is to have your `execute` method call a function instead of doing the actual processing. This makes it easily callable by any tool.

```
class Foo(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages)
        somefunc(parameters[0].value, parameters[1].value)

class Bar(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        somefunc(parameters[0].value, parameters[1].value)
        anotherfunc(parameters[2].value, parameters[3].value)
        return

def somefunc(arg1, arg2):
    #do something
    return

def anotherfunc(arg1, arg2):
    #do something else
    return
```

If you want those functions contained in the tool classes:

```
class Foo(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages)
        self.somefunc(parameters[0].value, parameters[1].value)
    def somefunc(self, arg1, arg2):
        #do something
        return

class Bar(object)
    def __init__(self)
        #stuff
    def getParameterInfo(self):
        # list parameters for UI tool
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.somefunc(parameters[0].value, parameters[1].value)
        self.anotherfunc(parameters[2].value, parameters[3].value)
        return
    def anotherfunc(self, arg1, arg2):
        #do something else
        return
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.  I thought I may have to create a module and import it but this supports my needs better.

Comment: this was very helpful and easy to implement in cases where I collected all parameters in the very first lines of `execute()`. The rest of that method could then just be copy-pasted into something like `run()`. Awesome.